# Adding composite component programmatically

Tags: jsf, composite-component, omnifaces

I would like to include below composite component programmatically:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="sampleBean" />
    <composite:attribute name="autoCompleteMethod"
        method-signature="java.util.List autoCompleteMethod(java.lang.String)" />
</composite:interface>
```

In [Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components), there is a function:

```
// Programmatically include composite component.
Components.includeCompositeComponent(someParentComponent, libraryName, resourceName, id);
```

However, it isn't clear to me how to specify the `autoCompleteMethod` in the obtained UIComponent instance. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `includeCompositeComponent()` returns an `UIComponent` instance representing the composite implementation.

```
UIComponent composite = Components.includeCompositeComponent(someParentComponent, libraryName, resourceName, id);
```

All of its attributes are available as a `Map` by `UIComponent#getAttributes()`.

```
Map<String, Object> attributes = composite.getAttributes();
```

You can use [`Components#createMethodExpression()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Components.html#createMethodExpression%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to create an EL method expression. Assuming that you intend to specify `#{bean.complete}`, here's an example:

```
MethodExpression autoCompleteMethod = Components.createMethodExpression("#{bean.complete}", List.class, String.class);
```

Now, just set it as attribute!

```
attributes.put("autoCompleteMethod", autoCompleteMethod);
```